# Use a UITextVIew

Tags: iphone, objective-c, interface

I wanted to post some text in a UITextVIew.
I wanted the user inserisse.
As messages tomore be inserted into a queue to another as in a chat.
How can I do?
Thanks

Comment: Is "inserisse" Italian for "insert"?

Comment: Yet another google translator failure.

Answer (score 0):

There's a great open source project here that could be of help: http://github.com/lashad/PTConversation